# Connecting VPS cPanel to actual IP

Tags: php, cpanel, vps, centos6

I don't know, if it is OK to ask server-related questions on SO. If its not OK, please tell me.

I have a **VPS** from RamNode, built on **CentOS 6**.

I have installed LAMP and created ftp and mysql accounts, databases using putty.

However, when I enter to the free cPanel that is provided by RamNode, I see no databases and when I look to the File Manager, it points somewhere else, other than the actual directory.

I have **2 FTP accounts**, **2 MySQL databases** and **2 MySQL users** and **none of them** appears on my cPanel.

Also it says **0/0 E-Mail accounts**.

How can I connect my cPanel to the actual server?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if your host installed cPane, ask them

Comment: @Dagon you are right, I opened a ticket. But, I think it can happen to other people too, so we also can try to find a solution, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

They said, because it is a **free** cPanel and it is just a **cPanel DNS Hosting**, these areas and numbers are just placeholders.

If anyone encounters the same problem, they want you to upgrade to the paid version. I think it will be applicable to all VPS providers.

Comment: sounds like B.S to me. my free cPanel works as expected.

Comment: @Dagon it is true actually, when i test it, only DNZ Zone Editor works, other areas are just there, no work.